# Can't connect SSD1327 I2C

Tags: arduino, i2c, oled

I just recieved 2 OLED displays SSD1327 128x128 16bits, 1.5", but I can't connect them to my arduino uno R3.

I first tried with the Adafruit library, set the address 0x78 as printed on the display, but it didn't work.
Then I tried with the address 0x3C according to the 7bit-8bit encoding difference, but it didn't work aswell.
So I tried to find the address with a I2C scan sketch, and the things start going weirdly :

When the display is correctly wired up, the sketck blocks at the line Wire.endTransmission();
But when the display GND is not connected to anything and the display VCC is connected to 3v3, the sketch detects an I2C device at the address 0x3C, whis is the good one!
And I get this for the both displays I recieved.

I tried with an other I2C device (SSD1307), to check my wirering or the sketch if anything could be wrong, but no, I got the expected results: the device was detected only when it was well wired.

[image]

Any ideas ?
Do you think the displays are dead ?

EDIT : shematics added

Comment: So how did you wire them? Post schematics and how you actually wired it.

Comment: That's really not a schematic, but good enough to convey the idea. OK, what exact display module you bought, as SSD1327 is only a controller, which does not tell much about the hardware, just the protocol. Does the display have a name, datasheet or manual?

Comment: Yeah but the wireing is very simple. Just 3 or 4 wires.
I bought the SSD on Aliexpress, and I have not really much informations.. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002021894569.html
On the PCB there is the number : GME128128-02 v3.1

Comment: Um, so you bought a random display with no documentation how to wire and use it?

Comment: Yes, it's cheap, and I've never had a problem before. I do a lot of research before I buy. It's a hobbit, I can't afford to spend a fortune